# Select specific column base on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to select column "H1" to "x"(x = 5 or x = 7) columns to the right, but I want for the selection to change based on a number in a specific cell "L2".

[image]

Comment: You want to select h1:hx or what

Comment: Do you mean something like this `Range("H1:H" & Range("L2").Value)`  ?  (this will get rows down from H1)

Comment: Or perhaps `Range("H1").Resize(, Range("L2").Value)` ? (this will get columns to the right of H1)

Comment: I need for Column H to get selected all way down and I need for selection can be expand stating from H:X when X= Cell "L2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand from your post, I am guessing according to the screen-shot you've attached maybe something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DynamicSelect()

Dim LastRow As Long, NumofColumns As Long
Dim Rng As Range

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
NumofColumns = Range("L2").Value

' set the range object
Set Rng = Range("H1", Range("H1").Offset(LastRow - 1, NumofColumns))

' if you must Select (not recommended)
Rng.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: formula work good, I have adapted base on my needs, I really appreciate that time you took to help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Sub rangeselect()
n = Cells(2, 12)
Dim rng As Range
Dim Str As String
Str = "H1:H" & n
Set rng = Range(Str)
rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Kemal thank you for your suggestion, I have try your code but is not what I'm looking, I believe that I didn't express my self correct, I need for Column H to get selected and I need for selection can be expand stating from H:X when X=L2